# Reading ALL custom properties on Exchange Server with EWS

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I would like to read all "Custom properties" from EWS-Items. I do have the names of the properties (e.g. "duration" oder "distance") but I did not create them (my clients did).

I guess I will have to use "ExtendedProperties" of the "Item" class. But when I use Item.Bind() with a Property-set I need to know a GUID which I don't have! Microsoft says (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633697%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx):
"Create a GUID identifier from the GUID that was used when the extended property was created."

I don't have these GUIDs because I did not create the properties.
I guess the only chance is to use Item.Bind() without a specific property set. Would that slow down the process (I need to call this for every item in the mailbox)?

I basically would like to iterate with a clause like this: 
if (extendedProperty.PropertyDefinition.Name == "duration")

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to recover it by name using the PropertyDefinition and property type (MapiPropertyType):

**//Search for "duration" property**

```
 Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition =
    new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition
        (DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, "duration", MapiPropertyType.String);    

    EmailMessage msgMod = EmailMessage.Bind(service, msgComplete.Id, 
                          new PropertySet(extendedPropertyDefinition));

    ExtendedPropertyCollection colProp = msgMod.ExtendedProperties;
    foreach (ExtendedProperty prop in colProp)
    {

       //Iterate properties

    }
```